# Carregar pins seletivamente via Mysql - Maps API

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, mysqli

Tenho uma dúvida quanto a carregar pins de um banco de dados Mysql.

Digamos que eu tenha um banco de dados que armazena várias latitudes e longitudes e necessite carregar alguns pins a partir deles, via API do GMaps.

Entretanto, isso me gerou uma dúvida: Minha intenção é carregar um mapa baseado na localização do usuário e carregar os devidos pins, caso eles correspondam àquela localização. Entretanto, para fazer isso, seria necessário percorrer TODO o banco de dados a cada movimentação do usuário? Se eu tiver um grande número de lat/long isso não afetaria o desempenho? Me sugerem uma forma melhor de fazê-lo?

Comment: Não entendi direito qual é a duvida exata, parece que tem vários pontos misturados numa questão só. Você já tem o código que carrega os pins ou não? Quanto a movimentação do usuário, nao faz sentido pesquisar o banco a todo momento. Pode procurar o que está em torno dele, e só atualizar depois que ele andou mais que n metros ou km. Por exemplo, se carregou o que tem 5km em volta do usuário, pode recarregar só depois dele se afastar pelo menos uns 500m do centro da pesquisa anterior (é um exemplo apenas). Ou pode organizar em setores, carregando por partes e descartando os mais distantes.

Comment: Então.. mas como meu sistema julgaria o que está a 5km em volta do usuário? Teria que consultar o banco inteiro, não?